# distutils create a .egg-info directory

Tags: python

For some reason, using

```
python setup.py sdist
```

started creating a folder called .egg-info
whenever I run it.

This did not happen before. What is this file? How can I disable it?

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256417/python-packages-and-egg-info-directories

Comment: Did you switch to using `setuptools` from `distutils`?

Comment: no, but i did include find_packages (from setuptools import find_packages)... that's it?