# What does a "Could not find .egg-info directory in install record" from pip mean?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Since updating the the most recent `setuptools` (6.0.1) I get an warning (yellow)

```
Could not find .egg-info directory in install record for ...
```

for all the packages I've updated. For example, when updating Twisted I get

```
Could not find .egg-info directory in install record for Twisted from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/T/Twisted/Twisted-14.0.2.tar.bz2#md5=.... in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

The package updates seems to succeed, however.

What does this warning mean? What can I do to respond to it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256417/python-packages-and-egg-info-directories
I am not totally sure either.. Maybe this will help you in the right direction.. best of luck

Comment: Wild guess: did you install some packages, like Twisted, without pip?

Comment: If your answer to @EOL is yes, did you also upgrade to a new version of `pip`? Because IIRC, it was around 1.5 that `pip` started being able to upgrade some non-`pip`-installed packages, and because that's not always safe it may warn you about it.

Comment: See [this distutils-sig thread](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2013-August/022528.html); I'm not sure if it's what I was thinking about or not…

Comment: @EOL: I don't recall. I've been maintaining with `pip` for quite some time now, so my guess is that all my packages have been previously updated using it. If that (or anything else) is the case, is there something I can do about it?

Comment: I'm not sure, unfortunately…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to have been [a bug introduced in 6.0.1](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issue/262), [fixed](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#id187) in `setuptools` 6.0.2.

Answer (score 23):

For me upgrading `setuptools` did not work, what did work was updating pip:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
```

(I've included setuptools too to handle both problems)

Comment: i had to run `python.exe -m pip install --upgrade setuptools pip`. After the upgrade the warning disappeared.

Comment: Thanks, this answer saved lots of my time